# Welches ist hier gängiger? "bei jmdm bekannt sein" oder "bei jmdm populär sein"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

> In den 90ern waren die Fantastischen Vier bei den Jugendlichen sehr bekannt.
>
> In den 90ern waren die Fantastischen Vier bei den Jugendlichen sehr populär.

Welcher Satz ist hier gängiger? "Bei jmdm sehr populär sein" oder "Bei jmdm sehr bekannt sein"? Ist das eine Dialekt und das andere Hochdeutsch?

Comment: Willst du ausdrücken, dass man sie gekannt hat oder wie beliebt sie waren?

Comment: Ich möchte ausdrücken, wie beliebt sie in den 90ern waren. :)

Comment: Na dann ist dir bestimmt jetzt klar, was zu nehmen ist :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn Du ausdrücken willst, wie beliebt die F4 in den 90ern waren, dann schreib doch einfach Folgendes:

> In den 90ern waren die F4 bei den Jugendlichen sehr beliebt.

Comment: " bei jmdm sehr populär sein" passt nicht in diesem Kontext?

Comment: Doch, nur klingt das recht hochgestochen. Eine Zeitschrift würde das z.B. so schreiben, wobei 'sehr beliebt' immer richtig ist